# Magento dev site redirects to live URL

Tags: magento, webmin

I'm having trouble creating a Development website on webmin, I have created the file structure containing all the magento files from my 'Live website' and I have made a copy of the MySQL database but it seems as though the Subdomain I created redirects to the old domain (live website). The things I've done are as followed:

1. Changed the path in core_config in MySql to the subdomain ( dev.*****.co.uk )
2. Changed the database name in local.xml to the new database I want it to look at.
3. Made an A record pointing to the correct IP address for the sub domain.
4. Changed the permissions to 0774 in case permissions caused an issue.

I don't know what else I need to do. It goes to the live website every time I try and reach the development website. Is there something I'm missing or haven't done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have done everything you need to.

Try:

1. Make sure it is not **cache** related. Clearing your cache (just delete /var/cache from your Magento root)
2. Make sure it is not **browser** related. Try in an incognito window (Chrome loves to cache redirects)
3. Make sure it is not **server** related. Try putting a plain text file in your Magento root and load it in a browser. If even this file redirects to your live site then the problem is not Magento related.
4. Make sure the you are actually looking at the **right** **database**. Try putting incorrect details in your local.xml file and clear the cache. Do you see an error (you should)?

Comment: I feel so stupid, i cleared my cache and it worked i was certain that switching browser would have the same effect as clearing my cache. Thank you its always the little things.

Comment: Don't feel bad, at least you will know what to do if you have the same problem in future!